# How do I properly fit this tail with IK?

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have this tail rig that I'm using IK to animate with. I'm fairly new to rigging and IK, however, I've come this far:

[image]

The problem is I want to have more control over the curve that the IK Target creates, for example, this rig only bends downwards, I'd like to be able to change the bend without having to rotate any parts as it causes bones to move out of place.

Any tips/help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps use a spline IK: The chain of bones conforms to a curve object. Then you can control that curve in a separate rig using the Hook modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect time to use a pole target! Essentially its another bone that the IKed bones will bend toward. Also if you make its parent the IK target, its especially easy to use.

Comment: Can you add some more detail? This answer tells the questioner what they need, but doesn't really explain how to do it.